# Highlight Duplicate Rows When Conditions Met in Multiple Columns i Excel

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, formula

I am looking for help setting up a conditional formula in Excel that highlights a row when two conditions are met. The goal is to flag when multiple users are working in the same zone at the same time.

In dataset below, I want to highlight when both conditions are met: the status is "IN PROGRESS", and there are multiple rows in the same zone.

I would like to see row [3] and row [9] highlighted because Jenny and Steve are both "IN PROGRESS" in zone "2".

What I would like to see

[image: What I would like to see]

`=AND($B1 ="IN PROGRESS", COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)>1)`

I have tried different combinations of AND, COUNTIF, and COUNTIFS but am always getting row [7] highlighted because it is "IN PROGRESS" and there are other rows in zone 1 even though none of them are in progress. Thank you for any help.

What I am seeing

[image: What I am seeing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AND` and `COUNTIFS`; add the `IN PROGRESS` check as an additional criterion in the `COUNTIFS`.

```
=AND($B1="IN PROGRESS",COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,$B1)>1)
```

[image]